# Making Rows Out of Column in SAP HANA Calculation View(Scripted/Graphical)

Tags: sql, join, union, hana

**Main Source Data**:

```
TYPE    ID  VERSION      Column_NAME    VALUE
A   WXYZ    0            COLUMN_A       ABC
A   WXYZ    0            COLUMN_B       DEF
A   WXYZ    0            COLUMN_C      CHI
A   WXYZ    0           COLUMN_C       JKL
A   WXYZ    0           COLUMN_D       MNO
```

After applying Union on source I got the below table:

We have many other Rows based on Type, ID, Version.

Data After Union(Similar to):.

```
TYPE    ID     VERSION  COLUMN_A    COLUMN_B    COLUMN_C    COLUMN_D
A    WXYZ       0         ABC         <Null>    <Null>      <Null>
A    WXYZ       0        <Null>        DEF      <Null>      <Null>
A    WXYZ       0         <Null>      <Null>     CHI        <Null>
A    WXYZ       0        <Null>       <Null>     JKL        <Null>
A    WXYZ       0        <Null>       <Null>     <Null>     MNO
```

OUTPUT I need:

```
 TYPE   ID       VERSION    COLUMN_A    COLUMN_B    COLUMN_C    COLUMN_D
    A     WXYZ         0          ABC         DEF        CHI      MNO
    A     WXYZ         0          ABC         DEF        JKL      MNO
```

I tried taking max of the Column_A,Column_B,Column_C,Column_D.using an aggregation node. but the problem is Design Studio does not support CV in which maximum of any attriubute is taken.

Can anybody suggest any other way of doing it?

Comment: What do you means NULL in column D? I'am asking for why for me the NULL means NO so i use this code: if (IsNull("field"), 'N', if("field"='Yes', 'Y', 'N'))

Comment: @MatheusOliveira I have edited the last column, you can check now,Null means no value.it appears as ->(?) in HANA

Comment: can you post your SQL and what OUTPUT do you want so I can help you better?

Comment: @MatheusOliveira actually I am working on a Graphical Calculation View in SAP HANA, so there is no script.

Comment: @MatheusOliveira I have updated with main Source, Please check now!

Comment: Hi Swatkat, I have the same problem, did you find a solution please? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @dieuhuynh,
I did this as suggested by LarsBr:
I see. In that case you’ll have to use the left outer join technique for “rotating” your data set. For that you project each attribute individually and join on the shared key (type, id, version)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Swatkat

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply do the "pivot-by-union-and-aggregation" in a new calculation view that takes your original view as input?
The UNION + AGGREGATION nodes perform the `MAX` aggregation on strings alright.

Comment: If you check data in Column C, It is not possible to take maximum, as we will get only 1 line then in the output, @LarsBr.

Comment: I see. In that case you’ll have to use the left outer join technique for “rotating” your data set. For that you project each attribute individually and join on the shared key (`type`, `id`, `version`)